# Does the performance of OpenFL Android applications differ based on what language was used to code it in

Tags: android, haxe, openfl

I am under the impression that you can code OpenFL in Haxe, AS3, and JavaScript. And if I want to use OpenFL for making Android apps with JavaScript... will the performance be worse or it does not matter?

http://www.openfl.org/

I very much inclined that it's going to be worse, which sucks, as I only know JavaScript and not Haxe...there should be js to haxe guide somewhere. Also I read that AS3/AS2 causes performance degradation for Haxe.. So I have no reason to think JS won't.

Though in beginning my apps are just information browsing. Which doesn't need to get 60 FPS..

Also, I am unable to find any type of documents about getting started as JS developer for OpenFL...it's only Haxe?

Please comment for any more information or modifications of things that bother you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only code with Haxe in OpenFL.

> Read in Developer section of OpenFL website
>
> At the heart of OpenFL is the **Haxe** programming language.
>   Haxe uniquely targets other programming languages as the output. As a
>   result, a Haxe application has the power to target C++ (for native
>   platforms), JavaScript (for HTML5) and Flash from the source. This is
>   mature, well-supported, and is what enables OpenFL to take a different
>   approach -- instead of compromising, OpenFL creates a middle-ground
>   between scripting languages and native languages. You can get the
>   performance and strict typing you need for excellent results on mobile
>   or desktop, while leveraging your investment for the web. OpenFL
>   provides the tools and libraries necessary to make it simple to wrap
>   this cross-language power and make it easy to deliver great results,
>   everywhere.